# How to combine DjangoObjectType and an additional field in one query?

Tags: python, graphene-python, graphene-django

I have a DjangoObjectType class and its query as below.

```
class ExampleType(DjangoObjectType):
    class Meta:
        model = Example
        interfaces = (relay.Node,)

    order_number = String()
    group = String()

    def resolve_order_number(self, info, **kwargs):
        return "order number"

    def resolve_group(self, info, **kwargs):
        return "group"
```

here is the query;

```
class Query(ObjectType):

    all_data = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        ExampleType,
        filterset_class=ExampleFilter,
    )

    def resolve_all_data(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Example.objects.with_annotations()
```

I need to add another field that is not in ExampleType to the query result. So I have created another ObjectType class as follows.

```
class CombineData(ObjectType):

    datas = List(ExampleType)
    error_info = String()

    def resolve_error_info(self, info, **kwargs):
        return "ERROR INFO"
```

And I have changed the query like below.

```
class Query(ObjectType):

    all_data = DjangoFilterConnectionField(
        CombineData,
        filterset_class=ExampleFilter,
    )

    def resolve_all_data(self, info, **kwargs):
        return Example.objects.with_annotations()
```

However, I'm getting many errors such as `DjangoConnectionField only accepts DjangoObjectType types` error. If I change the `all_data` type as `Field` there is no error but I also need to use my `ExampleFilter` in the combined class but it's an `ObjectType` class.

How can I fix this issue?